# Why does routing defined after app.use isn't returning anything after get requests?

Tags: express

I am new to node.js and express.js and I am practicing the basics of server creation. I found out that if I write app.get after app.use that code simply doesn't work.

I tried googling various combinations of "why app.use express.js 404" but found nothing.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


// 1) Add a route that answers to all request types
app.route('/article')
.get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Get the article');
})
.post(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Add an article');
})
.put(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Update the article');
});
// on the request to root (localhost:3000/)
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<b>My</b> first express http server');
});


// 3) Use regular expressions in routes
// responds to : batmobile, batwing, batcave, batarang
app.get(/bat/, function(req, res) {
    res.send('/bat/');
});


// 2) Use a wildcard for a route
// answers to : theANYman, thebatman, thesuperman
app.get('/the*man', function(req, res) {
    res.send('the*man');
});
// app.get does NOT return anything thats defined beyond this method call
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry, that route doesn't exist. Have a nice day :)");
});
// this will not be work unless moved above app.use
app.get('/welcome', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<b>Hello</b> welcome to my http server made with express');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route handlers are checked for a path match in the order they were defined.

Once you define this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry, that route doesn't exist. Have a nice day :)");
});
```

The response has been sent and `next()` has not been called so no more route handlers in the chain will be called.

Your 404 route handler should be the last route handler defined.  The idea is that if no other route handler has handled this request, then you must not have one and it must be a route that you should return a 404 for.  But, you can only know that no other route handler will handle this request if you put this one last in the chain (and thus define it last so it will be last in the chain).

---

To explain a little more, each time you do `app.use()`, `app.post()` or `app.get()` or any other in that family, it adds a route handler to an internal routing array and it adds them to that array in the order that the code ran.  The first route to register goes at the start of the array, the last one at the end of the array.

When a request comes in, Express starts at the beginning of that array and looks for the first handler that matches the path and type of the incoming request and calls that route handler.

If that route handler never calls `next()`, then no more route handlers are ever called for that request.  It's done.  If that route handler calls `next()` then Express continues looking in the array for the next matching route handler.

So, you can see that your `app.use()` 404 handler never calls `next()` so Express will never proceed to look for more matching route handlers for that request and thus the route handlers that are declared after that are never found and never called.